# plot single row of 2d numpy array against 1d list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot a single row from a 2-dimensional numpy array against a 1d list in python.  For example, I would like to plot using matplotlib row 'i' as below

```
  |0 0 0 0 0|
  |1 1 1 1 1|
i |2 2 2 2 2|
  |. . . . .|
  |n n n n n|
```

against

```
[0, 100, 200, 300, 400]
```

What I have currently is:

```
plt.plot(list1, 2dimArray[i])
```

but this is not working.  I had this functionality working when I was plotting 1d lists against 1d lists but I had to go multidimensional and chose numpy.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: If `A` is your 2D array, and `x` your 1D list, does `plt.plot(x, A[i,:])` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data from your comment below, this works for me:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.arange(0,1100,100)

In [3]: y = np.random.rand(6,11)

In [4]: i = 2

In [5]: plt.plot(x, y[i])
Out[5]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1043cc790>]
```

[image: plot of row 2]

The the thing is that the `x` and `y` arguments to `plot` must have the same shape (or at least the same first entry to shape).

```
In [6]: x.shape
Out[6]: (11,)

In [7]: y.shape
Out[7]: (6, 11)

In [8]: y[i].shape
Out[8]: (11,)
```

Perhaps one of your items generated by your program doesn't *actually* have the shape you believe it does?

This should also work if you use a list together with a numpy array (`plt.plot` will probably convert the list to an array):

```
In [9]: xl = range(0, 1100, 100)

In [10]: plt.plot(xl, y[i])
Out[10]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10462aed0>]
```

Comment: This is the error I am getting:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Comment: Can you tell us what `b.shape` and `a.share` are?

Comment: x: 1d list constructed as such [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]

y: 2dim array constructed as such np.zeros( (6,11) )

Comment: @user1535701 I can still get it to work using the data you supply.  See my edit.  Are you sure the shapes match?

Comment: could it have to do with the fact that my y variable is an _array_ and my x variable is a _list_?  or do the two play nicely with one another with respect to plotting?

Comment: @user1535701 No, it shouldn't be the list thing.  It works if I use `x = range()` instead of `x = np.arange()`  What solved the problem?